# "The carrot, which was orange, was tasty"

Tags: commas, restrictive-clauses

Can someone point out the differences in the meanings of the following 2 sentences :

1. The carrot, which was orange, was tasty
2. The carrot which was orange was tasty

What all possible inferences can be drawn from these 2 sentences ?

Comment: What is the source of these two sentences?   What inferences do you draw from the sentences.  It is better if you can explain what you think the answer is, and explain why you are unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The carrot, which was orange, was tasty**
*The carrot was tasty and was coloured orange*

The commas are parenthetical commas, and enclose extra information about the preceding words ('the carrot')

> which determiner, pronoun (ADDS INFORMATION)
>
> used to add extra information to a previous clause, in writing
> **usually after a comma:**
>
> *That bar on Milton Street, which by the way is very nice, is owned by Trevor's brother.*

**The carrot which was orange was tasty**
*Among some carrots of more than one colour, the single one that was coloured orange was tasty.*

The absence of commas make 'which' a pronoun referring to the carrot (the one out of a number of carrots which was orange and not some other colour).

> which pronoun (USED TO REFER)
>
> used as the subject or object of a verb to show what thing or things
> you are referring to
>
> *You know that little Italian restaurant - the one which I mentioned in my letter?*

[Which (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/which)

[Commas for parenthesis (Grammar Monster)](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_for_parenthesis.htm)